# Is it possible to capture the coordinates of the last letter drawn with TEXT function?

Tags: r

How can I programmatically capture the X coordinate of letter "r" in "better" string in the example? I'd like to capture that coordinate in order to dynamically draw the arrow next to it. Can this be done in R? It can be done in SAS ...with some difficulty.

```
x<-c(1,3)
y<-c(3,3)
plot(y~x, type="c", ylim=c(-1,5), xlim=c(-3,3), col="red") 
abline(h=0,v=0, lty=3)
text(0.3, -2.5, xpd=T, "Group 1 better", adj=0)

#manually draw the arrow
arrows(x0=1.3, x1=3, y0=-2.5, y1=-2.5, length=0.1, code=2,xpd=T)
```

[image]

The obvious approach is to count number of letters in the string and add that number to the X coordinate of the string. This approach will probably work well in most cases but may not work well in if the size/style,angle of the text changes. I am wondering if there is a an easy way to capture the last position of the string.
SAS does it by placing the arrow relative to the internal coordinates of the previous string.

I would also like to know how to capture the last coordinate of any other graphical element as well - if possible at all.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use strwidth to get the string width, and add an extra character's width for a bit of space:

```
> arrowlabel = "Group 1 better")
> sw = strwidth(arrowlabel)
> xpos = 0.3 + sw + sw/nchar(arrowlabel)
```

Then draw your arrow starting at x=xpos.

Comment: I mentioned this solution in my question. This solution would certainly work as long the size, style, font or angle of my string would remain the same.

Comment: @MaxCherny Isn't that precisely why `strwidth` accepts arguments like `cex` and `font` so that you can specify that information when calculating the width?

Comment: Note that strwidth doesn't count the number of characters in the string, it actually works out the length of the string in plot coordinates, so it handles proportionally-spaced fonts and character sizes. If you are plotting at an angle with the srt parameter well then you'll just have to do a bit of sine-cosine stuff to compute the end location.

Comment: Yes, this solution works well in almost all cases. . SAS can capture the position of any previously drawn graphical element, including an arrow or  a pie chart - I was expecting a solution along those lines here. However, this is certainly good enough for most of all my figures. In fact, I like this approach more than I like the SAS approach. thanks a  lot !!!

Comment: Just to clarify: SAS allows to draw a graphical element (text, line, bar...) relative to the last position of the previously drawn element. I think R approach is actually easier.

Comment: That's because SAS is a dinosaur and probably thinks it still has an x-y plotter attached to it from which it can read the coords of the pen... j/k